# NoneType object has no attribute cursor

Tags: python, mysql, cursor, mysql-python

I am calling below 2 lines in a loop so thousands of connections are open at a given time. Sometimes this code raises an exception saying `'NoneType' object has no attribute cursor`.

Why is this thing happening? Is MYSql running out of db connections?

```
conn=MYSQLdb.connect(params)

conn.cursor()
```

Comment: Sounds likely. Is there a specific reason you make the connection inside the loop? Can't you re-use the same connection? Or close them when you're done?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel system requirement is to add multiple rows parallaly so one connection won't work. I am closing connection as soon as I am done with it. So there are hundreds of http requests coming in the system at a time and each request triggers an entry in database. So I can't use a single connection for all of them.

Comment: note It sound like you might already know this but since your phrasing is ambiguous I'd like to note that 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'x' exception indicates you tried to get an attribute of a None(null) object.

Answer (score -2):

Today I met this issue. I read the MySQL DB doc and I found something that can help me. This maybe helpful to you. Now, the doc says:

```
db=_mysql.connect("localhost","joebob","moonpie","thangs");
```

So, now you have an open connection to DB and want to do a query. Well, there are no cursors in MySQL, and no parameter substitution, so you have to pass a complete query string to `db.query()`:

```
db.query("""SELECT spam, eggs, sausage FROM breakfast WHERE price < 5""")
```

For now, maybe this library makes some changes, then the attribute cursor been replace by query.

Comment: the next line also form the doc cursor([cursorclass])
MySQL does not support cursors; however, cursors are easily emulated. You can supply an alternative cursor class as an optional parameter. If this is not present, it defaults to the value given when creating the connection object, or the standard Cursor class. Also see the additional supplied cursor classes in the usage section.